# Sending user to their browser's Home Page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, browser

Is it possible to get a browser's home page using Javascript?

I'd like to place a link on a page that goes to the home page set in the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: simplified answer

Identify browsers and:

- Call  window.home(); for all browsers
- Call window.location.href =
  "about:home"; for IE

To do so you can use http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/

> The jQuery Browser Plugin is an addon
>   for jQuery that makes it easy to
>   uniquely identify your visitors'
>   browsers.

---

Other solutions:

```
 <script language="javascript">
    function gohome(){
      if (typeof window.home == 'function'){ // The rest of the world
        window.home();
      } else if (document.all) { // For IE 
        window.location.href = "about:home";
      } else {
        document.write("<p>Please click on your browser's Home
button.</p>");
      }
    }
  </script>
```

This is [via this website](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg35006.html). The poster states that there are issues to target Safari. This can be fixed using [this other website](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/06/targeting-safari-30-with-css/).

Using the CSS tricks explained there you can then do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   isSafari3 = false;
   if(window.devicePixelRatio) isSafari3 = true;
</script>
```

and use this in the script above to call the correct function:

```
if (typeof window.home == 'function' || isSafari3)
```

Comment: Looking at it now, this answer doesn't seem to be 100% correct. `about:home` does not seem to work in IE 8, and `window.home()` only works in Firefox (not Safari or Chrome).

Comment: In case this helps others: had a confounding problem on a legacy web app I just started maintaining after upgrading from FF 21 to FF 22.0: it had an iframe with `name="home"` and Javascript like `var url = top.home.location.href`, but this broke since apparently `home` is a function in Firefox [that cannot be overwritten like it could in 21.0].

Answer (score 4):

Default home page (default new tab) URL:

Google Chrome:

```
https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab
```

Firefox and IE:

```
about:home
```

Opera:

```
opera:speeddial
```

Safari:

```
http://livepage.apple.com
```

---

To find out the default home page URL of your browser, go to your home page and type `location.href` in the console. Note that the browser might redirect you to your locale, so you'll need to find out the page before redirection (it happens on Chrome).

---

If you're using this [browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38946222/3356679) code you can use this one-liner to get the correct url:

```
var homepageurl = browser == 'gc' ? 'https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab' : browser == 'op' ? 'about:speeddial' : browser=='sa' ? 'http://livepage.apple.com' : 'about:home'
```

Browser detection code JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/ncb4n882/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a cross-browser solution.  In IE you can use the HomePage behavior and call [navigateHomePage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531398(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For FF and the like: `window.home();`

For IE: `location = "about:home";`

Answer (score 1):

window.home() didn't work for me in FF37, but this was fine:

```
location.href = "about:home";
```