# How can I make a JavaScript alert before a page closes?

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I want to write JavaScript code that would, when I close the current HTML page, display an alert message like "Are you sure?"

I want to take the value of the button from the alert message, whatever the user pressed. How can I do this?

Comment: If your are talking about choice it should be confirm() not alert()

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `beforeunload` is never fired in Opera.

For supporting that browser, you probably have to  build some page-leaving-detection engine yourself (observing links etc).

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

Check out this post: [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {
            return "alert message";
    });
});
```