# QR-encode email with recipient, subject and body?

Tags: qr-code

I need to QR-encode an e-mail message with custom recipient, subject and body, so most mobile QR-Code scanner apps will automatically create an e-mail with the encoded recipient, subject and body. Of course this will depend from the features of the mobile QR-Scan app. But isn't there an international standard for such a purpose?

Answer (score 0):

A Qr-code can contain many different types of information:

1. Contact information
2. Calendar event
3. E-mail address
4. Phone number
5. Geo location.
6. SMS
7. Text
8. Wifi network
9. URL

(from [here](http://notixtech.com/blog/9-qr-code-data-types))

The E-mail adress does'nt allow us to store body message.

The only information that could work is the URL, using the mailto scheme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

For example, encode `mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body`

This generates the following QR-Code.

[image: Email To]

It doesn't open the mail app on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S2), but asks to add the email Adress to your contacts.

What you could probably do is to direct to one of your server, that will then redirect to the mailto URI. (I'm not sure that you can redirect to mailto , cf [Django: how to redirect to mailto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960669/django-how-to-redirect-to-mailto)), howewer, you could create a big link on the page that mails to your adress.

Answer (score 0):

The `mailto:` scheme is a pretty good choice, since it lets you specify a subject and body:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368

It's not guaranteed that the scanner, or e-mail client, supports or honors it of course.

See also the old DoCoMo MATMSG format. Barcode Scanner supports this on Android for example, and has space for an email body.

https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents
http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/developer/make/content/barcode/function/application/mail/