# need to have an alertbox in jsp inorder to close the browser

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a function in my jsp to keep track of the session.

Wen the session gets expired, I need to show an `alert` that the session is over. The box should hav an `ok` button which, when clicked, I want to close the browser. I did using `confirm` but confirm seems to have `Ok` and `CANCEl` button. I need only Ok button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sessionTimeout = 180;
        function Timeout()
        {
            var counter = sessionTimeout;

            sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;

            if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
                window.setTimeout("Timeout()", 1000);
            else
            {
               alert("Your current Session is over.")

            }
```

==========================================

I don't need any confirmation from user, just alerting user the session is over and onclicking ok browser should close

```
        }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [confirm box](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm) instead , It should be like

```
function close_window() {
    alert("Close Window?");
    windows.close();
  }
}
```

**See Also**

- [how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: If you read the OP question properly, the OP doesn't want to use the `confirm` box.

Comment: The confirm dialog can also be denied. so there is no use.

Answer (score 0):

Just alert the user and then close the window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionTimeout = 180;
    function Timeout()
    {
        var counter = sessionTimeout;

        sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;

        if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
            window.setTimeout("Timeout()", 1000);
        else
        {
           alert("Your current Session is over.");
           window.opener='x';window.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```