# Close currently opened tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried `window.close();` to close the currently opened tab but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? My scope is to run a JavaScript script that automatically closes a manually opened tab.

Thanks.

Comment: See [How to close current tab in a browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

Typically in javascript (or other flavors of javascript), this is done with...

```
<a href="#" class="close">Close Window</a>

$(".close").click(function {
    window.close();
});
```

Note that this will only work on the tab that contains the link that was clicked. It will not close other tabs open in your browser.

I'm giving a +1 for each comment on the question, too.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention that I want the tab to close automatically after the script does its job.

Comment: That's fine, add the `window.close();` line to the end of the script

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this answer [how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Have a look also at the comments of this answer, where [Ryan Joy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247268/ryan-joy) says:

> "This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method." In other words, you can only use JavaScript to close a window/tab that was spawned via JavaScript"

Also notice that:

```
window.close();
```

works only for Internet Explorer where a popup message appears asking if user agrees for current tab/window to be closed.

In Firefox, Chrome only works for empty tabs and tabs/windows opened via "window.open()" method as mentioned above.

Comment: So, for tabs opened manually there is now way to close them via JavaScript on Firefox?