# On click of anchor tag , I want to close the current tab and redirect to a new url

Tags: anchor

On click of anchor tag I want to close the current tab and redirect to a new URL in new tab. I want this functionality to work for IE,mozilla,firefox and safari .Can anyone please provide me the javasciprt for the same . The reason i am trying something like this because i donot want users to click back button of the browser and get back into the site . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code utilizes jquery to accomplish the task; it can be done in plain vanilla javascript as well. It should work across all (at least the more modern) browsers.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#open").click(function(){
      window.open(window.location.href);
    });
    $("#openandclose").click(function(){
      window.open(window.location.href);
      window.close();
    });
  });
</script>

<a id="open">Open New Window</a><br />
<a id="openandclose">Open New Window and Close Old Window</a>
```

Comment: I edited my answer to actually close the current tab and open a new tab. However, there is a catch. According to the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373625/close-current-tab you can only close a window that you have opened. So I would recommend opening your main window in a new tab if you can so you can have this control.