# Can an extension close a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is in continuation of: [Script to close the current tab in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169228/script-to-close-the-current-tab-in-chrome)

I'm trying now do it in an extension instead of a tampermonkey script, I have `"matches" : ["*://*.youtube.com/*", "*://youtube.com/*"],` in my manifest file, and the js script is simply `chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);` or `window.close();` but both don't close a youtube.com page that I open.

Could it be that it's also impossible to close a tab with an extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`chrome.tabs` is not available to content scripts, so if that's in your code, it fails with an exception.

[`window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) has a caveat:

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the `window.open()` method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: *Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.*

I'm not sure if it applies to content scripts - but suppose it does.

You can make it work by adding a background script (that has access to `chrome.tabs`) and either detect navigation from there, or just message the background script from a context script to do it.

1. Messaging the background:

   ```
   // Content script
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({closeThis: true});

   // Background script
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
     if(message.closeThis) chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
   });
   ```

   I would recommend adding `"run_at": "document_start"` to the content script's configuration, so it fires earlier.
2. Better yet, you don't need a content script. You could either rely on `chrome.tabs` events, or `chrome.webNavigation` API. You probably need the host permission (e.g. `"*://*.youtube.com/*"`) for that to work (and `"webNavigation"` if you use it).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first one works. The second one does not. It looks like you're very knowledgeable about chrome extensions so i want to consult you as I'm a total beginner, I want to make an extension that will close a youtube tab after the video has ended and that tab isn't focused for over a minute. How do you know what go to which script (content or background)? For example, Does YT events (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) go to the content script?

Comment: Also, do you have any tips or where to start for making that extension?

Comment: Everyone should carefully read the [Overview page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), it contains a lot of important information. SO can help if you have [well-defined questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) might be of use.