# How to close current tab in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I'm new in chrome extensions and i'm trying to create a simple extension that close current tab if match an element class.

This is my code in content script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

    if ($(".watchdogedit").length > 0) {

        setTimeout(CLOSECURRENTAB,3000);
    }   
});
```

I need the "CLOSECCURENTTAB" function..

Help me!

EDIT:

DONE IT!!

content script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($(".watchdogedit").length > 0) {
     setTimeout(closeTab, 3000);
  }     
});


function closeTab() {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "closeTab"});
}
```

background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type == "closeTab") {
        chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Here is the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373625/close-current-tab

Comment: @Pugazh - that was not a chrome extension duplicate

Comment: @Pugazh not same question..
i want to close any tab with chrome Api and not with simple js