# angularjs modal modal-dialog close

Tags: angularjs, popup, modal-dialog

Please excuse my ignorance but I am new in angularjs, I want to display a popup that has 2 buttons (OK and Cancel) 
OK : close the popup and the browser
Cancel : close the popup

I am using modal-dialog to display the popup
My html code is :

```
<modal-dialog show='dialogShown' dialog-title='My Dialog'>
          <p></p>
          <p>Are you sure ?</p>
          <button ng-click="closeWindow()">OK</button>
          <button ng-click="closeDialog()">Cancel</button>

</modal-dialog>
```

My controller :

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,myservice) {

    $scope.dialogShown = false;
    $scope.showDialog = function(){
        $scope.dialogShown = true;
    }

    $scope.closeWindow = function(){
        // I need to close the popup AND the window
    }

    $scope.closePopup = function(){
        // I need to close the popup 
    }    
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: by window you mean the browser tab?

Comment: Yes I mean the browser tab

Comment: Have you created the modal-dialog directive ? <modal-dialog> is not a native html tag so you have to create the directive on your own like htis : http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/ or try to use Bootstrap modals or Angular Material library

Comment: Hello @Alburkerk,
I tried the bootstrap modal, but I have the same issue, I can close the popup, but not the browser tab.
Apparently it's impossible due to security purpose.

Comment: Oh you want to close the window totally my bad I didn't get it correctly. According to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373625/close-current-tab it is not possible if you didn't create the tab from the website (only possible on past versions of IE because ... IE)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to be able to close the current tab of the browser, you should use the `$window.close()` function.

For more informations about this function, read the [window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/close) and the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) documentations.

**EDIT** : Like it's wrote in mozilla doc for `window.close()` :

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

A workaround is to self (re)open the window then close it :

```
window.open('', '_self').close()
```

Angular way (with $window) :

```
$window.open('', '_self').close()
```

But this is a bug exploit and should not be used in production because it will probably be fixed in futur versions of browsers.

Comment: Thank you Vincent, but when I try to use $window.close(), but it shows me this error in the console :  
    Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: I edited my post, tell me if it awnser your question

Comment: same problem : 
    Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.