# How to close parent window in an Apps Script Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, sandbox

I have a web app in Google Apps Script and I need that when I have click in a Button, the browser tab closes. I tried with different solutions but it does not work as I require it.

This is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Demo Close tab</h1>
    <p>When you click the button, you must close this tab.</p>
    <button>Close</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        // window.close();
        // window.top.close();
        // window.open("","_top","").close();
      });
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my GS code

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index");
  
  return template.evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
  .setTitle("Demo Google Analytics");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373625/close-current-tab).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs [HTML Service: Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions):

> The setSandboxMode method now has no effect when called.

Your Google Apps Script runs in an iframe by default, regardless of any attempts to change the sandbox mode. I strongly suspect the sandbox settings will prevent you accessing the parent `window`, but you might try `window.parent.window`.

Answer (score 0):

**According to Javascript Documention:** [Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.`

Answer (score 0):

Web Apps are usually [standalone script projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) that, as per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions) on restrictions applied in the `IFRAME` sandbox mode (which is, as of 2021, the [only mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode) available), has the following sandbox flags (corresponding to the `sandbox` [attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox)) set on the `HTMLIFrameElement` Web Apps are served in:

| Flag |
| --- |
| allow-same-origin |
| allow-forms |
| allow-scripts |
| allow-popups |
| allow-downloads |
| allow-modals |
| allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox |
| **allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation** |

Note the last flag - this is the reason for being able to initiate navigation when a user clicks on an element but not when calling methods like `window.top.close()`, `window.location.reload()`, or `window.location.replace(<url>)`.

---

This seemed to not be strictly enforced for *bound* script projects up until September 2021, but it is now. As of now, there are several open issues on the Issue Tracker reporting that the auto-closing Web App windows stopped working - please follow them if you want to get updates on whether or not Google will reconsider enforcing the flag:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198071205
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198323022
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198073648 (status "Won't fix" but open for a feature-request)