# Close currently open browser tab on button click in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried some many codes but none is helping my requirement is to close the tab which is open on button click in a page.

```
window.open("about:blank", "_self");
window.close();
```

This piece of code on click function in angular but it showing blank page on current active tab but not closing the window.

it not a anchor it is a button and here its using angular code we need to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close Current Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373625/close-current-tab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: If JavaScript did not open it, you do not have the ability to close it. I doubt any of the hacks work.

Comment: @epascarello actually the above two lines pasted is a hack but that hack showing a blank page and not closing the tab is there are any other use hack do you know

Comment: The links people said are dupes have all the hacks. Problem is things that worked years ago were patched by browsers.....

Comment: @epascarello how to make it work for the latest browsers can please help me out.

Comment: In the angular>=6, it is not allow to close tab and it gives me `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.` warning. @Hel_UI