# how to close current browsing window in javascript using firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to close the current browsing window in JavaScript. I've tried the following code. It works in Chrome and Safari, but doesn't in Firefox.

```
var win = window.open('', '_self', '');
win.close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score -2):

You will need JavaScript to do this. Use `window.close()`:

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
   close();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This won't work properly as the `close` method only works for windows opened using JavaScript. Please take the [tour] when you can. Thanks!