# Confirm box "Cancel" not working?

Tags: javascript, popup, prompt, confirm

I'm having problems with this code.. Basically, I'm making a website right now, and when I'm making a Confirm pop-up box when visiting the website, I make the dialogue, no problem, but when it comes to the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons, they both allow access into the website. What I want is for the "Ok" button to proceed the user into the site, but the "Cancel" button to close the tab. How do I do this?

This is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  var r=confirm("If you agree you are at least 18 Years of Age, press Ok. Otherwise, press Cancel.");
  if (r==true) {
    x="You pressed OK!";
  }
  else {
    x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you know its not working..??? you are not alerting anything so how do you test it.?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aD6n2/1/

Comment: Its working fine for me. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/E43gD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you CAN do is empty the document content and tell the user that he/she is not allowed to view the site's content, you can't close the browser window/tab.

but if you are opening your site from another page using `window.open()` then open it in OK/true condition in the confirm message in that page else close the window using `window.close()` in the cancel/false condition

to clear out content

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wzqFB/1/

Answer (score 0):

First of all the confirm works perfectly. Can check over here http://jsfiddle.net/E43gD/

Second, if you need to close the current tab using javascript,
you need to use

```
window.close();
```

More over here [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can place this script at the end of body. So whenever user presses OK, you can simply execute empty function and whenever user clicks on "no", you write a function redirect him to another page for example