# Close Firefox tab programmatically?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I need to close firefox's current tab, either by javascript or any other method, if possible.

I had found somewhere the following solutions:

```
window.close();
```

and

```
 var myWin = window.open('','_self','');
  myWin.close();
```

and both the codes are working in:

1. Chrome 56.0
2. Opera 44.0
3. Internet Explorer 11
4. Microsoft Edge 38
5. Safari 5.1

But not in Firefox, I want this working in Firefox.

I have Firefox 52.0, Please Suggest any method,...

Thankyou

Comment: Have you read this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302387/close-firefox-tab-from-javascript
?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open(document.URL,'_self','resizable=no,top=-245,width=250,height=250,scrollbars=no');
window.close();
```

This should work on chrome and firefox, collected from [Close firefox tab from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302387/close-firefox-tab-from-javascript)

Comment: How are you using it? Tested it on Firefox and Chrome, it should be working.

Comment: I have used it through custom HTML file and in console scripting both, but failed in firefox.

Comment: Modern security standards do not permit this behavior.