# How to close a window from button in JQuery UI dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to close the current window with the click of a button, inside a JQuery UI dialog box.

I tried with `window.close()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sessionReason").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Submit": function() {
        window.close();
      },
      "Cancel": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#cancelSessionButton").click(function() {
    $("#sessionReason").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Example</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <input id="cancelSessionButton" type="button" value="Cancel Session" class="redButton" />

  <div id="sessionReason" title="Reason">
    <p>Please provide the reason for cancelling the session.</p>
    <div class="inputRow">
      <textarea id="sessionReasonBox" class="reasonBox"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3bxM/

Comment: in jsFiddle, you are in an iFrame, it is a particular case. Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window it seems that `window.close()` should work

Comment: I tried in my code too window.close() is not working!!!

Comment: Note that in the newer versions of Firefox, you are not going to be able to close the browser via javascript.  See this discussion: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/966137

Answer (score 1):

Did your script open the window? Firefox 2 and later do not allow scripts to close windows that they did not open. `window.close();`

This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method.