# Close browser with javascript without confirmation box in Firefox 24 and more

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a firefox add-on and try to close a window with javascript.
I'm using Firefox 24. When I try this:

```
window.close()
```

The window close but Firefox always ask me to confirm the closure. I don't want to see this confirmation box.

I tried to set `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` in `about:config`, that will allow you to use `window.close()` function to close the window but it doesn't work.

I tried to disable the option `browser.warnOnQuit` in `about:config` but it doesn't work.

Has anyone a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Comment: You tag this as `firex-addon-sdk`, are you trying to close a content window via an add-on? Could you be more specific? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normaly you can't close a window that was not opened by the `open` function in js.
There is a little hack for that and I do not recommand this, because the user is maybe dissatisfied with this behavior..
But, try this:

```
window.open('', '_self', '').close();
```

Comment: Thank you C Sharper for your answer.

I already tried this but it doesn't work. The confirmation box still appears.

Here is more details:

I realized a firefox add-on which open some url (for each url -> open a window in fullscreen). This add-on use javascript to open each new window in fullscreen. I created a button to close direct all and if I click on it, I have the confirmation box for each windows.

The problem I constated is if I try to close a window with javascript, this confirmation box appears. If I try to close normally, the confirmation box appears too.

Thanks for your help