# jsf can I close browser tab from bean?

Tags: java, jsf

My application is managing software, and for user convenience, I want to allow them to open multiple tabs for changing parameters of more than one record at a time. But after finishing whatever they doing, the tabs stays open, and I got some complains about that. So basically my question is:

If there's any way to close browser tab that sends a request to method in my backing bean? for example:

JSF page:

```
<h:commandButton value="Public score"
   action="#{assignmentBean.publicSelected()}">                        
</h:commandButton>
```

Bean method:

```
public void publicSelected() {
    application.setAssignmentStatus(done);
    dataAccess.mergeEntity(application);
}
```

is there any way to add something after merging command and close browser tab that activated method? Thanks for help

**FULL CODE FOR SOLUTION** I'm bad with mixing JS and JSF, so for any of you that are also bad at this I post full code solution using Tiago Vieira Dos Santos hint.

Now my button code looks like:

```
<h:commandButton value="Public score"
   action="#{myBean.doThings}">    
   <f:ajax execute="@this" onevent="pop"/>                    
</h:commandButton>
```

plus on bottom of page I added code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pop(data){
        if(data.status == "success"){
            window.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

now after method does what has to be done the window closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can be use the javascript command Window.close() then you can put it on oncomplete tag or call in you managed bean using the FacesContext.

See more in this [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: I'm so dumb when it goes to mixing js and jsf - could you post a code updating my code for button? I tried <f:ajax execute="@this" render="window.close();"/> but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Using an OutputLink and Javascript

```
<h:outputLink onclick="window.open('popup.faces', 'popupWindowName', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no'); return false;" value="#">
        <h:outputText value="open popup" />
</h:outputLink>
```

With this solution we got control over the appearance of the new browser window. And since there is no postback, there is no validation at all. This is the easiest way to open a new browser window when no model update is needed and no action has to be executed.

In order to implement a proper action handling we need to move the decision whether to open a new window to the action listener.

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.openPopupClicked}" value="open popup" />

public void openPopupClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    // code to open a new browser window goes here
}
```