# Javascript dialog window close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want to Close `window.dialog`. I open window as below,

```
window.$('<div align="center" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><iframe src="'+fdt+'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>').dialog({ 
     modal: true,
     width: 460, 
     height: 450,
     title: "Serial"
    });
```

After open dialog, when press enter key on input I want to close this window. Please Help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#stsr').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
          //I Want to close this window
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the DIV an ID

```
window.$('<div id="dialog" align="center" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><iframe src="'+fdt+'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>').dialog({ 
     modal: true,
     width: 460, 
     height: 450,
     title: "Serial"
});
```

Then you can refer to it later:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stsr').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            $("#dialog", window.parent.document).dialog("close");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the keypress code running inside the iframe? I assumed it was running in the parent document.

Comment: I've updated the answer to access the parent document. This will only work if they're in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window).
`window.close()` should do the trick:

```
if(e.keyCode==13){
      close();
}
```