# Phonegap (Android) is window open with navigator.app.loadUrl

Tags: android, ios, cordova, window, navigator

I use

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(URL,{openExternal: true})
```

to open a new window an will close it if my fallback fires.

i tried `var ref = navigator.app.loadUrl(URL,{openExternal: true})`

and in my fallback

```
ref.close()
```

without any success.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

to open the new window with url

```
window.open(URL-LINK,'_blank');
```

[to close window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076307/3819810)

Or this pretty simple:

```
 window.open('','_self').close();
```

Comment: it starts the inAppBrowser i think, but this one i dont need.

Comment: well ... i tried your's too. The window don't opens in a new window but it's important to do that.