# automatically close internet explorer after interval

Tags: javascript

i want to automatically close internet explorer after running php code or after 50 seconds. i got following JavaScript but doesn't work in this case.

```
<script language='javascript'>
var win = window.open('http://www.google.com',     '1366002941508','width=500,height=200,left=375,top=330');
setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, 10000);
</script>
```

please help me, i am trying different code doesn't work

best regards,

Comment: Your code is working. Try it in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/db46kbd6/

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Is your browser allowing open a pop up?

Comment: yes @Leandro pop up is blocked

Comment: how to open above code in same window.

Comment: If you want to close the self window, this post is a duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Comment: he wants the window to be closed automatic. Not manually.

Comment: @Leandro please read this article. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: He can do it with the code that he has already.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code works fine in IE8

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loaded()
{
    alert("Beep!");
    window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 5000);
}

function CloseMe() 
{
    window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loaded()">
Hello!
</body>
```

Comment: What is the difference with the code of the user that is actually working? Please recheck your answer.

Comment: Could you provide more information in order to know what is the change that you made for IE takes your code but not the user's code? Because are the same.

Comment: Tested: with IE8 is still working the code of the user.

Comment: Is the window with the google.com page closing after 10 seconds? I guess not.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes your code required click to close the window.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to close a window/tab in IE (or any browser) using javascript but you will not be able to close the application/browser. That being said if you want to automatically close a window after 50 seconds you could use the following:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {window.close();}, 5000);
```

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the OP question?