# html window open-close by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to close a window open by this javascript written in my landing html page .

```
window.open(location,"_self");
```

in the location html page I have a button where I tried with

```
<div onclick="javascript:self.close();">Xyyyy</div>
<div onclick="javascript:window.close();">Xxxx</div>
```

None of them work.

Note: my condition in I have to open the new window in the same place.

any help is appriciated

Comment: Only the script that opened a window is allowed to close it.

Comment: You need to open a new window to close with JavaScript. A new separate window or tab.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search on the subject and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome) is what i found.

**html** *(not mine)*

```
<input type="button" name="Quit" id="Quit" value="Quit" onclick="return quitBox('quit');" />
```

**JavaScript** *(not mine)*

```
function quitBox(cmd)
{   
    if (cmd=='quit')
    {
        open(location, '_self').close();
    }   
    return false;   
}
```

[There is even a test page.](http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/window_close_tester.htm)

I did a search for a bunny rabbit too (which isn't mine either).

[image]

**Updated** : Mar-12-2015

I did a search on the subject and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window) is what i found.

I did a test with this code and confirmed it is not supported. The comments are good reading.

**JavaScript** *(not mine)*

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    window.close();
  }
}
```

**html** *(not mine)*

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>

<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>
```

Comment: I need to do this in the same window. This opens an other window. that is not expected for my scenario

Comment: I dont think that is even possible in current "safe" version of internet browsers. I ran into this issue too, and the best thing you could do, is to not use window.open, but create a custom "window" by javascript, which is only controlled by you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get completely what you are trying to do but here are some tips:

```
window.open("https://slackoverflow.com");
```

is used to open an entirely new window(can be used to open local files as well ofc)

```
window.close();
```

window.close() Closes the tab.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Page yada yada</a>
```

And this can be used to open a link or page in a new tab. If you play around with these for a little itll start to catch on.

I hope some of these ideas help and will help you put together what you are trying to accomplish :)

Comment: @Edamame, so are you looking to open a new 'tab' in a browser? There are a few ways with just html attributes, but I don't know of any way in javascript, that doesn't mean there isnt one though.