# Automatically submit the form, then close the window after 5 seconds without prompt

Tags: javascript, html

With the code below, I can get the web page to automatically submit the form properly. I'm trying to figure out how to have the script delay for 5 seconds, then close the window without asking the user if they want the window to close.

This page will be used inside our company to launch a product provided by a vendor. Because it will be inside our network, the window will most likely be IE for anyone who uses it.

I cannot get the script to close the window after 5 seconds. I am trying to accomplish this without using jQuery. This is what I have so far.

```
<html>
<body>
<br/>
<h3>Launching GE Web Viewer ...  Please Wait</h3>
<br/>
    <form id="frmLaunchViewer" method="POST" action="https://geview.abc.org/startwebviewer.jnlp">
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="MyUserName">
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="MyPassword">

        <script>
            document.getElementById('frmLaunchViewer').submit();
            window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 500);
        </script>   

        <script>
            function CloseMe() 
            {
              window.close();
            }
        </script>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Close an opened page by javascript =/= close the browser, a program.

Comment: You generally can't close a browser window unless it's a window your code opened with `window.open()`.

Comment: 5 seconds is `5000` milliseconds (you forgot a `0`). And you might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: If you're posting the form, the page will refresh, wiping any existing timers. Set some sort of variable, perhaps `localStorage`, to indicate that you've submitted the form then you can _try_ redirect - closing probably won't work.

Comment: Appears to be a simple typo; 500 is not 5 seconds, it's half a second.

Comment: window.close() may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of Pointy. I'm assuming opening the browser to the page using a .bat file would make no difference, correct? Thanks for catching my typo blex. I'm not 100% sure that the 5 second delay is needed in order for the form submission to go through. This was more for the benefit of the user who clicks on the shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Evan Knowles said, if you submit a form, that'll refresh the page. You should use ajax to post the form:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
           window.close();
       }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://geview.abc.org/startwebviewer.jnlp", true);
xmlhttp.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("frmLaunchViewer")));
```

Waiting 5 seconds is useless, unless sendig the form's data takes 5 seconds. It's better to use an ajax callback than hoping that 5 seconds is enough to finish the process. If you really need that, see  blex's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById('frmLaunchViewer').submit();
        window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 5000);
    </script>   

    <script>
        function CloseMe() 
        {
          close();
        }
    </script>
```

Please check these -

[How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp