# Trigger CTRL+W event by javascript code

Tags: javascript

Can you just help me to provide javascript code which simulates CTRL+W event.
Basically CTRL+w is used to close current browser tab. Here i want to perform similar operation through Javascript code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```js
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 119 && event.ctrlKey){   
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Ctrl-W pressed");
  }
});
```