# Close own tab after confirm accepted in Js

Tags: javascript

I have a `confirm()` method that launches in the opening of a page. I want this page to be closed if the OK option is selected... Is there a solution ?

I've read that **you can't close window that were not created by a script** is it absolute truce ?

In my idea it were something like that :

```
if (confirm("Leave")) {
    close();
}
```

But it does not work and this is the console output :

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: Didn't you even try it?

Comment: be more specific window.close();

Comment: I tried both ofc but as I've said it seems that it is not possible to close a tab like this.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp

Comment: @E.Maggini It would have worked if it was that simple I will repeat my self : This does not work if the window hasn't been created by script

Comment: not a repeat if you made the edit after my comment, my friend. ;-)

Comment: @YehiaAwad the natural behaviour if no "window" specified is to select the tab/window you are in

Comment: @E.Maggini It was in the original post look the edit log

Comment: What browser? Are you run it from some `userscript`?

Comment: And then there's this <a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a>  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

which seems to say you can open a new window in self and then immediately close it

Comment: @vp_arth ho yeah perfect I haven't seen that post before. Thank you !

Comment: @E.Maggini I invite you to read the post vp_arth just post before. Ty for trying anyway :)

Comment: Not the same post...but ....shrug..see ya around.