# How to open Chrome from Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I have created a webpage that works best with Chrome. If the user opens this page from Safari, I want to put a button that says "Click here to open this page in Chrome". Upon clicking this button, Chrome should fireup and load the specified URL.

Is there a way to do that? Or even just to launch Chrome from Safari?

Comment: there is no way to do this

Comment: No, there is no way to execute a program from a browser action alone. The user would either need a plugin installed in the browser to allow for that, or OS/Browser that had some kind of url scheme setup to do such (eg how mail: url scheme can launch default mail app). Which by default they do not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to this within the browser, but here a few work-arounds. You could ...

- Make a button to copy your URL to their clipboard so they can paste it in Chrome
- Send the user to a download link if they don't have chrome (just ask them if they have chrome or not)
- Close the tab in the browser after the URL is copied

  - You could use `window.close()` or just `close()`, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076307/3783155).

These are just some thoughts. It's the best anyone could do for a problem like this. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a way, if you want to do this, make the button, and set the href to the link, but at the beginning, delete ‘https://‘ and replace it with ‘googlechromes://’, for example ‘googlechromes://YouTube.com’ if you go to that link in safari, it will ask, “do you want to open this page in chrome?” And if you click yes it will open chrome over safari