# How to close the current tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, window

This is what I've tried:

```
<html> <head> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
var parentWindow = this;
 function closeWindow() { 
// window.top.close(); this.parentWindow.close(); //window.open('','_parent',''); 
//window.close(); 
// var x=confirm('Are You sure want to exit:'); //if(x) window.close(); /*var childWindow = window.open("GAJANAN", "New Tab Window", "width=700,height=700"); setTimeout(function(){ childWindow.close(); }, 1500);*/ } </script>
 </head> <body>
 <br> <a href="javascript:closeWindow();">Close Window</a> <br><br> <a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a> <br><br><br> <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet --> <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.close();opener.window.focus();" >Close Window - javascript:window.close();opener.window.focus();</a> </body> </html>
```

Comment: I think a window/tab can be programmatically closed only if it was programmatically opened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can only close windows/tabs that you create yourself. That is, you cannot programmatically close a window/tab that the user creates.

For example, if you create a window with ***window.open()*** you can close it with ***window.close()***.