# I want to add an exit button at the end of the quiz, how can i do that?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code am working on and i wish you could help me get a code to put at the end of me question

**Below is the html tag**

```
<div id="result" class="container-fluid result" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 1px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; background-image:url('./img/giphy-downsized.gif'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

Below is the javascript code:I would like to add a button so i can exit.

```
 if(currentQuestion == totQuestions){
    container.style.display = 'none';
    resultCont.style.display = '';
    resultCont.textContent = 'Your Score: ' + score;
    return;
    }
  loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
}

loadQuestion(currentQuestion);

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _exit_. Would a simple link to a page work for you?

Comment: The exit here means to completely close the web page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: @kyle iys true but does not work on all the pages

Comment: @Jonah-ElEtuaful I would at least edit your question and add that as something you tried and that it did not work.  How the question is currently worded, it is a duplicate.  You may get better help as well.