# Detect Page Close Event

Tags: javascript

What is the best way for page closed event detection ?

I have a page and I want to check if the page get's closed.
I have to do something if the user closes the page.

I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window) and it didn't work.

I will rollback progress if user leave.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write the code in project.

   C#:

   ```cs
   using System.Web.Services;

   [WebMethod]
   public static void AbandonSession()
   {
     HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
   }
   ```

   VB.NET:

   ```vb
   Imports System.Web.Services

   <WebMethod> _
   Public Shared Sub AbandonSession()
     HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon()
   End Sub
   ```
2. Add a script tag in between head tag of Default.aspx page and write following code:

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function HandleOnclose() {
       alert("Close Session");
       PageMethods.AbandonSession();
     }
     window.onbeforeunload = HandleOnclose;
   </script>
   ```

   Edit the function to serve your purpose and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use beforeunload in javascript, check this [example](http://codinghelpers.net/page-closed-event-detection-in-javascript/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        return 'Do something...';
    });
});
```