# How to close all others browser tabs using JS (Like imacros)?

Tags: javascript, imacros

How can we close all others browser tabs using Javascript like imacros command "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" ?!

Comment: ... sounds like a dangerous thing to do.

Comment: (imagine you open some webpages, and suddenly your browser closes)

Comment: @user202729 what you do ?! , it's programing question , not a reviews question !!

Comment: Well, Then show us what you've tried...

Answer (score 0):

"You can't close any tab via JavaScript. "This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method." In other words, you can only use JavaScript to close a window/tab that was spawned via JavaScript."
Source: [How to close current tab in a browser window? -Ryan Joy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window#comment2006744_2076307)