# What is the method for closing a tab with a button on the opened tab?

Tags: javascript

I want a user to open a new tab (tab 2) with a button in tab 1.
In tab 2 I want the user to be able to close tab 2 by clicking a (nicely-styled) button.
The Mozilla documentation gives an example like this

```
var windowObjectReference;
function openRequestedPopup(url) {
    windowObjectReference = window.open(url);
}
```

but if I use this on tab 2

```
function closeWindow() {
   windowObjectReference = window.close();
}
```

the console tells me that windowObjectReference is not defined, so not passed to the next tab.

```
<button onclick=self.close()  >Close</button>
```

also doesn't work. The console tells me that "self.close is not a function".

edit: the windowObjectReference is not passed to tab2, so using the close() method also does not work

```
function closeOpenedWindow() {
    windowObjectReference.close();
}
```

The console tells me again that "windowObjectReference is not defined"

Comment: Couldn't you assign onclick event and just do `this.close()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is enough to close the current tab (that the button is placed on):

```
<button onclick="window.close()">Close</button>
```

Note that depending on the browser, this will only work when the current tab was opened by a script itself and not manually by the user.