# Close the current tab and open new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Close the current tab and open a new tab using JavaScript. On Chrome or any other browser.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
window.setTimeout(function(){this.close();},1000);
```

Comment: current tab should opened from other tab. Otherwise it'll not close. No browser will allow to close the current tab if it opened manually because of security concern.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the current tab

   > You can't close the current tab until and unless it has parent
   >   reference

Its simple, if the current tab is opened by self I mean, you went to browser and typed the url in the url bar can't be closed with the javascript. Because of security reasons browsers will not allow these type of things.

If you try the following code

```
window.close();
```

you'll get following warning message by browser

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

If the tab is opened with window.open, right click on the link and opened on anchor tag then following should work

```
window.close();
self.close();
```

2. Opening new tab using the javascript :

`window.open("https://stackoverflow.com");`