# Close the window automatically after printing dialog closes

Tags: javascript

I have been provided with the attached file but I would like for it to close the window tab after it is printed.
I am not very technical, but any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Metapack Java script]

Comment: Post code as **text** please

Answer (score 0):

You can add `window.close()` after `app.endPriv()`
[How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: Hi Ben, I have tested this just now and unfortunately did not close the window

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure then. I would need to see some more code