# How to close current tab using swal alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert

I am using swal alert box, I just need to close my current tab when the user clicks on ok button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure ??",
        text: 'hii', 
        icon: "success",
        buttons: true,
        //dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        window.close();
      } else {
        window.close();
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: What relation is there between the "current tab" and when the alert is shown?

Comment: when page is fully loaded this swal alert is popup, when user click on ok button then current tab should be close

Comment: You mean the browser window tab?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Comment: yes browser window, but how i can use this in swal.

Comment: You have two issues: how to close a browser-tab (see link above, short answer: you can't) and how to get value from swal:  use `.then(..` https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises

Comment: see my updated code i using same, but getting warning. script may close only the windows that were opened by it

Comment: Right, so now you have one issue (you shouldn't change the question as you get fixes, maybe add an update, but not change completely).  How to close a window, which you can't: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Answer (score 1):

By using a customizing the confirm dialog from [Docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples)
You can use the following code below:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: "Error",
  text: "wrong user or password",
  type: "error",
  showCancelButton: false,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'OK'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    window.close();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

PEN: [CLICK HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJLVYg)

Comment: giving an error uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined.

Comment: Its works fine with me , lemme check again. i'll try to put the code in the built in code snippet of stackoverflow.

Comment: and also, i use a latest swal library. Try the code in your computer if it works. It's working fine with me with the included library.

Comment: can you please give me CDN for this.

Comment: alert.html:38 Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: @Akshay it's included in snippet.

Comment: see this warning alert.html:38 Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.