# simple function which should close the tab doesn't work (not a function)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function, which should `close` the **tab** if a user **clicks** a `button`. For some reason, I keep getting an error that it is not a function.

It's a simple function, and I have no idea why it wouldn't work...

> Uncaught TypeError: deny is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.html:183)

Any help would be welcome

**EDIT**: Thanks for pointing to other threads. It might be true that it wouldn't close the window. **BUT** why does it say that deny is not a function?

```js
function deny(){
  console.log("deny function executed.. :D ");
 window.close();
};
```

```html
<button id="deny" onclick="deny()">
 <span id="d">Close</span>
</button>
```

Comment: What is not a function? `deny()`? Please add the exact error message (and preferable a [mcve])

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: where is the error? The code runs successfully and prints log message. @Droom

Comment: when I click the "deny" button, I get a console log error deny is not a function. Thats why I'm baffled... it's a simple code. it should execute without a problem

Comment: The function has to be defined before the DOM node. Move it into the `<head>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it**. So you cannot close the current window by `window.close()` method.

Please refer this link.
[window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: How does this fix `Uncaught TypeError: deny is not a function`?

Answer (score 1):

`window.close()` will not work on windows that weren't opened with the `window.open()` method

Comment: window.open(location, '_self').close();

Comment: true, but doesn't answer the poster's question.

Comment: How does this fix `Uncaught TypeError: deny is not a function`?