# How to close the Browser Window using ZK framework?

Tags: zk, zul

I need to close the **Browser Window Tab**, please note not the window widget but the Browser window tab, using **ZK framework** version CE-9.0.0.

I have already tried the following code segments but no luck:

```
Clients.confirmClose(null);
Executions.deactivate(page.getDesktop());
page.setComplete(true);
page.removeComponents();
page.invalidate();
```

Is there any API or way to achieve this using ZK and/or JavaScript?

Is there any way to get the reference to the browser window tab, so that it can be closed programmatically, in ZK and/or JavaScript?

Please note: This window tab is opened manually & not by JavaScript or any other program.

Thanks,

RAS

Answer (score 0):

The JS to close a window is `window.close()`, this is a [well documented standard browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close). (also [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window))

From a ZK application (server-side) you can call this script via:

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("window.close()");
```

However this browser API has strict limitations: In modern browsers you can only close windows via close() that were also opened by javascript. So you can't [close the current window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close#Closing_the_current_window) in case the user navigated there manually - no way around that, except for using an old browser, which I won't recommend.

e.g. that's what you'll get in Chrome (#81)

[image: log message in chrome]

Comment: First of all, your assumption is wrong. I have gone through the documentation of each of the code that I have tried. Reason for trying them out is the multiple answers that are posted on various forums found on the Internet. Not only that, I have also gone through the links you posted already. Reason for asking the question is that I'm looking for solution specifically in ZK framework. This kind of question I could not find anywhere till now. Anyways, thanks for your reply.

Comment: ZK is running inside the browser, so that's the first place to look at, which APIs do browsers provide. If such APIs exist then there might be a matching convenience method in a framework such as ZK.

Comment: I removed my "snarky" comment.

Comment: I understand your point. So in that case I don't have any option to close the browser tab. :(

Answer (score 0):

Close the browser tab from a server directly is not allowed. But you can show a modal window to ask a user to close a browser tab like:

```xml
   <zk xmlns:ca="client/attribute">
    ...
       <window mode="modal" title="Close the browser tab">
           <button label="Yes" ca:onClick="window.close();"/>
       </window>
   </zk>
```

Because `close()` is invoked by users, it will close the browser tab. This could be an alternative. Although it doesn't close a browser tab directly, the modal window covers the whole page. Users can't do anything but to click "yes", so I think most users will just click "yes" to close.

**I found it works in Chrome 80, but will fail at Chrome 81. So it's not a good way**

Comment: I found it works in Chrome 80, but will fail at Chrome 81. So it's not a good way.