# How do I terminate a p5 sketch?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

My question is simple (probably). How do I terminate a p5 sketch? Basically what I mean is a way to press the stop (circle button with square) but with code. I've looked around and found stuff about noLoop(), but that doesn't seem to be what I need. I've also seen things about exit(), but I'm that doesn't work for me. What do I do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when you "terminate" your sketch? Do you want to show a particular screen / message? Do you want the canvas to be removed from the page? Something else?

Comment: @KevinWorkman What I mean is a way to press the stop (circle button with square) but with code.

Comment: @PatrickMartin Can you illustrate what you mean by the circle button with square to terminate the sketch ? As opposed to a Processing Java sketch with opens a window via the OS, p5.js sketches are rendered in `<canvas>` elements on a web page. Do you mean programatically closing the browser window which run the p5.js sketch you mention ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you want to close the active tab:
Insert this in the head:

```
<script>
    function closeWindow() {
        window.open('','_parent','');
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

```
<a href="javascript:closeWindow();">Close Window</a>
```

Also see this link:
[How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

2.If you want to remove the canvas/sketch only:
Insert this in your sketch.js file:

```
function mousePressed() {
  remove(); // remove whole sketch on mouse press
}
```

It will remove the canvas created by p5 and every element of p5.