# how can i navigate to previous page and close the current tab in angular..?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

im creating one button which navigate or open page in new tab.in this new tab i crated another button called "Close".i want to close the curent tab and back to previous page.How to do that...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: yes close current tab and redirect to the previous tab