# How to close new tab on clicking button which was opened with _blank <a> target attribute

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, menuitem

I am using the code below to open a new tab upon clicking a bootstrap button in a razor .cshtml page currently. I have a button in the new tab opened which returns to the main menu, but I would like to know how to close this tab, to effectively return to where the user was previously.

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <!-- Menu Item -->

    <li class="menuItem">
        <a asp-controller="New Tab Section Menu" asp-action="Index" target="_blank" class="menuItemLabel">
            <i class="fas fa-book-reader fa-lg" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>
            New Section Menu
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688958/6803592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.close()` in Javascript before, but this is mostly unavailable EXCEPT when you open a new tab with `target="_blank"` or by script.

In your case it might be worth a try.
Use a button with:
`<a href="#" onclick="window.close()">Return to base!</a>`

Browsers are very picky about this for security and useability reasons.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688958/6803592

Comment: this has worked exactly as i wanted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can't close browser tabs this simple.

I assume that you have a return button. What you can use `target="_self"` instead of `target="_blank"` so no tab will open and you can navigate back.