# how to close browser tab using js?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'd like to sign out user and close browser/tab using JS. i tried below similar code but it take no effect on the latest chrome.

```
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
```

can you help me?

Comment: [You can't close any tab via JavaScript. "This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method." In other words, you can only use JavaScript to close a window/tab that was spawned via JavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: my bro. that question is 10 years ago!! why you identify this as the same question?