# Tapestry: How to display an alert dialog from my Java code

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm actually writing a java code in the setupRender() method. Depending of a value provided by the server side, i would like to display an Alert dialog box to the user. By clicking on ok, the application should be closed.

I have not already found how to display an Alert dialog box with tapestry. Do somebody know  how to procedd?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'the application should be closed'. Is the browser window/tab supposed to close? Or the user session to be terminated? Or perhaps you meant to write 'alert box', not 'application'?

Comment: In fact, It's both. By clicking on the Ok button of alert dialog box, the user session should be terminated and the browser window tab closed

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a JavaScript-based solution. I added a third suggestion, using JavaScript, to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps the following two suggestions are useful.

### Suggestion 1 - Display a message using AlertManager

In the page class, inject AlertManager and add the message to it.

```
public class YourPage {

   @Inject
   AlertManager alertManager;

   Object setupRender() {
      // ...
      alertManager.alert(Duration.UNTIL_DISMISSED, Severity.INFO, "Love Tapestry");
   }

}
```

Then use the `<t:alerts/>` component in the page template file to have the message displayed.

Note: The user may dismiss the message, that is, make it disappear. But it doesn't 'close the application' (whatever it is that you mean by that).

### Suggestion 2 - Redirect to another page

The `setupRender` method can return different things. For example, it could return another page class, causing a redirect to that page. On that page, you could have the messages displayed and the session subsequently invalidated (if that's what you meant by 'application should be closed'.

```
public class YourPage {

   Object setupRender() {
      // ...
      return AnotherPage.class;
   }

}

public class AnotherPage {

   @Inject
   Request request;

   void afterRender() {
      Session session = request.getSession(false);
      session.invalidate();
   }

}
```

See the [Tapestry docs](https://tapestry.apache.org/page-navigation.html#PageNavigation-ComponentEventRequests&Responses) for details about what `setupRender()` can return.

### Suggestion 3 - Use JavaScript to display Alert and trigger Component Event

This approach uses JavaScript to display an Alert and subsequently trigger a component event via ajax. The event handler takes care of invalidating the session.

Note: Closing the current browser windows/tab with JavaScript isn't as easy as it used to be. See this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window) for details.

YourPage.java

```java
public class YourPage {

    boolean someCondition;
    
    void setupRender() {
        someCondition = true;
    }
    
    @Inject
    private JavaScriptSupport javaScriptSupport;
    
    @Inject
    ComponentResources resources;
    
    public static final String EVENT = "logout";
    
    void afterRender() {
        if (someCondition) {
            Link link = resources.createEventLink(EVENT);
            JSONObject config = new JSONObject(
                    "msg", "See ya.",
                    "link", link.toAbsoluteURI()
            );
            javaScriptSupport.require("LogoutAndCloseWindow").with(config);
        }
    }
    
    @Inject Request request;
    
    @OnEvent(value = EVENT)
    void logout() {
        Session session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) session.invalidate();
    }
    
}
```

YourPage.tml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_4.xsd"
    xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
    
    <h1>Hit the Road Jack</h1>
    
</html>
```

LogoutAndCloseWindow.js

```js
define(["jquery"], function($) {

    return function(config) {
        alert(config.msg);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: config.link
        });

        window.close(); // Legacy. Doesn't work in current browsers.
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window
    }

})
```