# Close browser from code in blazor server app

Tags: .net-core, web-applications, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm creating a web application in blazor server, the user should be able to close the browser by pressing a button. Is it possible and what is the best way to do it?

I already tried using IJSRuntime and close() but this approach doesn't work because the application is not started via open().

The target browser will be Ivanti Velocity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: No, I don't believe there's an all browser solution to close the window, so there is no best way of doing it.