# Using docusign returnURL to close tab

Tags: node.js, backend, docusignapi

I am working on a web app that uses DocuSigns embedded signing api. I have a form that opens in a new tab and then handles a returnURL once the user signs and submits the form. I wanted to know how I could get the form to close the tab completely once it is submitted rather than it going to a returnURL parameter.

I have tried setting the returnURL to null and looking through the embedded signing API to get any pointers on how I could not have a redirect, but this was to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just provide a `returnURL` parameter that resolves to a page with [some JavaScript to close the tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)?

Comment: The thread you linked doesn't actually have a working modern solution. There are many hacky workaround attempts, but they don't seem to be working anymore...

Answer (score 1):

If your `returnUrl` redirects to a backend resource, then redirect from there back to your app with some query parameter that indicates the client app to use some JS functionality to close the current tab.

If your `returnUrl` redirects to the client app, then just insert the query parameter directly to it.

Your redirect URL back to the client app should look like this:

```
https://www.myapp.com?close_tab=true
```