# Browser detection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

How do I determine the exact browser and version using JavaScript?

Comment: Make sure you aren't basing critical functionality on this test.

Comment: Here's a better link to explain object detection: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

Comment: Additional relevant answers can be found on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9847580/210336) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11219582/210336) dupe

Answer (score 377, accepted):

```js
navigator.saysWho = (() => {
  const { userAgent } = navigator
  let match = userAgent.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || []
  let temp

  if (/trident/i.test(match[1])) {
    temp = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(userAgent) || []

    return `IE ${temp[1] || ''}`
  }

  if (match[1] === 'Chrome') {
    temp = userAgent.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/)

    if (temp !== null) {
      return temp.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera')
    }

    temp = userAgent.match(/\b(Edg)\/(\d+)/)

    if (temp !== null) {
      return temp.slice(1).join(' ').replace('Edg', 'Edge (Chromium)')
    }
  }

  match = match[2] ? [ match[1], match[2] ] : [ navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?' ]
  temp = userAgent.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)

  if (temp !== null) {
    match.splice(1, 1, temp[1])
  }

  return match.join(' ')
})()

console.log(navigator.saysWho) // outputs: `Chrome 89`
```

As the name implies, this will tell you the  name and version number supplied by the browser.

It is handy for sorting test and error results, when you are testing new code on multiple browsers.

Comment: +1 from me as well. Sometimes, it's not about feature support, it's actually about the browser. Yes, the user-agent info can be spoofed, but when you're dealing with older browsers and circumventing their bugs (like FF 3's issue with not sending the Content-Length header for read-only AJAX POST messages), feature support just doesn't cut it.

Comment: Would be nice to know all the results this function returns...

Comment: @Diego agreed; for my browser it's `Chrome 33.0.1750.146`

Comment: Firefox 28 returns null with this

Comment: Confirmed that this property detects IE11, Chrome 38, and Firefox 32.  I checked the edit history and the first-version of the code from 2010 worked just as well.  Amazingly future-proof!

Comment: I love this! Thanks man!

Still, I just made a modification on the first and second last line. 
 I replaced: `navigator.sayswho=` with `navigator.browserInfo=` on the 1st line for better readability (i.e. so I won't wonder months later what it does in the code) and replaced `return M.join(' ');` with `return { 'browser': M[0], 'version': M[1] };` so that I can use it like this in the global scope: `console.log(navigator.browserInfo.browser);` and `console.log(navigator.browserInfo.version);` for better accessibility.

Sorry I guess  I did mess with it even though it said "Don't touch".

Comment: Here are a bunch of values I got: MSIE 8
MSIE 9 
MSIE 10 
IE 11 
Chrome 41 
Chrome 42 (using 42 Beta)
Chrome 43 (using 43 Dev)
Firefox 35
Firefox 37 (using 37 Beta)
Firefox 3 (usng 3.6)
Safari 8 
Safari 6 (using 6.1)
Safari 8 (using iPhone 6)
Chrome 4 (Samsung S5 native browser)
Opera 27

Comment: Is there any reason to not add `if (navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS') M[1] = 'Chrome';` after the initial `M` assignment? This would give us Chrome while on Chrome on iOS instead of Safari. My only idea against it is that the version may then no longer be correct.

Comment: @BradleyOesch You've succinctly demonstrated why you're never supposed to do browser detection. OK, so you know you're using Chrome on iOS. Except that's not Chrome, and doesn't have the same features as Chrome.

Comment: This one also does not work with all browsers - It detects the main 3 - IE, Firefox and Chrome very well - anything beyond that it breaks. Tried in older version of Opera in Symbian E61i belle, and in my UCBrowser. It returned Chrome in both cases...

Comment: @racl101 Really good idea, but you should watch out for the other two returns as well. Ignoring those could result in undefined browser and version, e.g. when using Edge 13.

Comment: I made a gist for this (also tried to make it slightly more readable) - https://gist.github.com/ocundale/13c5a632b3bdb8cadb59 
Thought it may be of use to some...Please feel free to edit if you find errors!

Comment: wouldn't it be better if `return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');` is `return ['IE', (tem[1] || '')];` ? having array with two elements all the time is more unified solution, I think.

Comment: Tested on chrome only for time being... if you wish to get the full version number, change the regx to `(vivaldi|opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([0-9|\.]+)` difference is the last bracket instead of `(d+)` it should be `([0-9|\.]+)` so number and the dot. also added vivaldi browser just incase :)

Comment: I tried opera mini from mobile with this code .. it returns browser name as Safari 4  and same from UC browser also. Is it normal?

Comment: Since you're going for the most terse and obfusticated code you can remove the `!= null`

Comment: This code is hardly readable. What is `tem`? What is `M`?

Comment: I need to identify QTWeb browser, but navigator.userAgent is coming blank there. Is there any other way to ientify ?
I have tried in latest QTWeb browser in windows7 system

Comment: snippet works but wish it was more readable to understand what's going on

Answer (score 71):

I recommend using the tiny javascript library Bowser. It is based on the `navigator.userAgent` and quite well tested for all browsers including iphone, android etc.

https://github.com/ded/bowser

You can use simply say:

```
if (bowser.msie && bowser.version <= 6) {
  alert('Hello IE');
} else if (bowser.firefox){
  alert('Hello Foxy');
} else if (bowser.chrome){
  alert('Hello Chrome');
} else if (bowser.safari){
  alert('Hello Safari');
} else if(bowser.iphone || bowser.android){
  alert('Hello mobile');
}
```

Answer (score 33):

This is something I wrote to get client info

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var check = function(r) {
    return r.test(ua);
};
var DOC = document;
var isStrict = DOC.compatMode == "CSS1Compat";
var isOpera = check(/opera/);
var isChrome = check(/chrome/);
var isWebKit = check(/webkit/);
var isSafari = !isChrome && check(/safari/);
var isSafari2 = isSafari && check(/applewebkit\/4/); // unique to
// Safari 2
var isSafari3 = isSafari && check(/version\/3/);
var isSafari4 = isSafari && check(/version\/4/);
var isIE = !isOpera && check(/msie/);
var isIE7 = isIE && check(/msie 7/);
var isIE8 = isIE && check(/msie 8/);
var isIE6 = isIE && !isIE7 && !isIE8;
var isGecko = !isWebKit && check(/gecko/);
var isGecko2 = isGecko && check(/rv:1\.8/);
var isGecko3 = isGecko && check(/rv:1\.9/);
var isBorderBox = isIE && !isStrict;
var isWindows = check(/windows|win32/);
var isMac = check(/macintosh|mac os x/);
var isAir = check(/adobeair/);
var isLinux = check(/linux/);
var isSecure = /^https/i.test(window.location.protocol);
var isIE7InIE8 = isIE7 && DOC.documentMode == 7;

var jsType = '', browserType = '', browserVersion = '', osName = '';
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var check = function(r) {
    return r.test(ua);
};

if(isWindows){
    osName = 'Windows';

    if(check(/windows nt/)){
        var start = ua.indexOf('windows nt');
        var end = ua.indexOf(';', start);
        osName = ua.substring(start, end);
    }
} else {
    osName = isMac ? 'Mac' : isLinux ? 'Linux' : 'Other';
} 

if(isIE){
    browserType = 'IE';
    jsType = 'IE';

    var versionStart = ua.indexOf('msie') + 5;
    var versionEnd = ua.indexOf(';', versionStart);
    browserVersion = ua.substring(versionStart, versionEnd);

    jsType = isIE6 ? 'IE6' : isIE7 ? 'IE7' : isIE8 ? 'IE8' : 'IE';
} else if (isGecko){
    var isFF =  check(/firefox/);
    browserType = isFF ? 'Firefox' : 'Others';;
    jsType = isGecko2 ? 'Gecko2' : isGecko3 ? 'Gecko3' : 'Gecko';

    if(isFF){
        var versionStart = ua.indexOf('firefox') + 8;
        var versionEnd = ua.indexOf(' ', versionStart);
        if(versionEnd == -1){
            versionEnd = ua.length;
        }
        browserVersion = ua.substring(versionStart, versionEnd);
    }
} else if(isChrome){
    browserType = 'Chrome';
    jsType = isWebKit ? 'Web Kit' : 'Other';

    var versionStart = ua.indexOf('chrome') + 7;
    var versionEnd = ua.indexOf(' ', versionStart);
    browserVersion = ua.substring(versionStart, versionEnd);
}else{
    browserType = isOpera ? 'Opera' : isSafari ? 'Safari' : '';
}
```

Comment: isn't it a little wasteful to always run all checks? seems pointless to check for Linux if you know it's a Windows isn't it...

Comment: @Matthias, thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to optimize the solution. The same logic can be applied in testing for browsers also.

Comment: yours is the best answer any body could give..thx.Made my life easy

Comment: @ArunPJohny: +1, for those horrible, rare times when you have no choice but to browser detect rather than feature detect. Do you keep this up to date, maybe in an OS project somewhere? Obviously since you wrote this answer, IE's stopped saying MSIE for instance...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry... This was a copy from an old version of EXTjs...

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Ah, well... :-)

Comment: all i see is `var var var var var var ...` Please, future coders who see this, don't do this. It's really not necessary and is a pain for project managers with OCD's to read.

Answer (score 29):

Here's how to detect browsers in 2016, including Microsoft Edge, Safari 10 and detection of Blink:

```
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
// Firefox 1.0+
isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
// Safari 3.0+
isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);
// Internet Explorer 6-11
isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
// Edge 20+
isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
// Chrome 1+
isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
// Blink engine detection
isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
```

The beauty of this approach is that it relies on browser engine properties, so it covers even derivative browsers, such as Yandex or Vivaldi, which are practically compatible with the major browsers whose engines they use. The exception is Opera, which relies on user agent sniffing, but today (i.e. ver. 15 and up) even Opera is itself only a shell for Blink.

Comment: The only correct answer in this page. Navigator object is no longer reliable after latest IE versions.

Comment: Have a look at this other answer for documentation on what these tests are build upon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/726097

Comment: @einjohn Also written by me :D Nice of you to link!

Comment: window.chrome.webstore is deprecated as of 06/12/2018, so it will evaluate as false and chrome detection would break.

Comment: @MihalyKR thanks, I've been working on a solution, will update soon.

Comment: this solution no longer works fyi

Answer (score 16):

It is usually best to avoid browser-specific code where possible. The JQuery `$.support` property is available for detection of support for particular features rather than relying on browser name and version.

In Opera for example, you can fake an internet explorer or firefox instance.

[image]

A detailed description of JQuery.support can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Now deprecated according to jQuery.

> We strongly recommend the use of an external library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)
>   instead of dependency on properties in `jQuery.support`.

When coding websites, I always make sure, that basic functionality like navigation is also accessible to non-js users. This may be object to discussion and can be ignored if the homepage is targeted to a special audience.

Comment: Sometimes you really need to know the browser, when the same features are supported in a different way. So, if making use of jQuery, $.browser is the right way, as indicated by user288744

Comment: If you'd like to do feature detection for such cases, imho it's best to detect the features you want directly as stated in my answer, *browser behaviour may change over time*. A good example is AJAX-Support which may me found out with $.support, or better yet directly: `xhr = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();`. It makes absolutely no sense test for $browser = 'ie' and then make use of `ActiveXObject` if you can directly test for `ActiveXObject`.

Comment: Sometimes you do need to know the browser version. Please make sure to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: When answering questions, I try to give the answer which suits 99% of the usecases, not 1%. And sometimes, the OP is asking the wrong question without knowing it. In 99% of the cases when you want to work around a browser specific shortcoming, you shouldn't detect the version, but the feature (e.g., as described) in order to cover other browsers with the same bug or because the behaviour of this verion may change in the future. But anyhow, when is this "sometimes"?

Comment: Sometimes, a side case, such as implementing an arrow indicator of where a download can be found to help the user that extra little bit. I would think you would have a much easier time doing this type of thing through version detection as opposed to feature detection.

Comment: I need to know the browser because I have two views for the same data, and one of them uses a CSS rule which is supported in opera on :hover but it's painfully slow. So I want to put a suggestion for opera users to use the other view, and not clutter the screen for other users.

Comment: @PhilRykoff - but you're not answering the 99% case of the question - you're answering the 99% case of another question, that you assume the questioner meant to ask, or should have asked. Maybe ask for clarification first?

Comment: Maybe you are right. Maybe I answered the question most people should have asked instead of the one they really asked while landing here ;) I don't now.

Comment: @Phil, you're right that sometimes the best answer is one that the questioner didn't even ask. However, I disagree with your application of that theory to this question.  Consider `window.onpopstate` (and please remember that a non-jQuery answer is most ideal to a question that never mentions jQuery) -- IE does not fire it for the initial view, in contrast to other browsers. Sometimes, to be robust, you must consider what browser you are dealing with to implement a feature correctly. Given the title of this question, that is *precisely* the information one would expect, and yours does not.

Comment: Uh, I hate to say this, but WHEN apart from testing your code with multiple browsers for compatibility purposes will you otherwise spoof your browser's configuration?

Comment: @BogdanD: `jQuery.browser` was deprecated in v1.3 and removed entirely in v1.9.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question that was asked. The question doesn't say "I want to do conditional code based on the browser", it simply asks how to get the value. How do you know they are going to do conditional code based on the answer? A perfectly valid use case is in an automated test where you might want to execute some javascript that logs which browser is being tested. Or maybe you're writing an internal diagnostic page. There are legitimate reasons for wanting to know what the browser is (or says it is).

Comment: I need browser name to show an icon of current browser to user. So don't judge only by your needs.

Answer (score 12):

This tells you all the details about your browser and the version of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>

<script>

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent language: " + navigator.systemLanguage + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this supported on all platforms?

Comment: checked in firefox,IE and chrome....works there....please do let me know your feedback

Comment: It looks like all my browsers are Netscape. Either your code sucks or I am high

Comment: @erdomester apparantly it worked for others too...... it's working for me too

Comment: all my browser's are Netscape 2

Comment: what do u mean?could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: 'works on my machine' is not acceptable approach of web development.

Comment: These methods are deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 7):

All the information about web browser is contained in navigator object. The name and version are there.

```
var appname = window.navigator.appName;
```

Source: [javascript browser detection](http://web-design-lessons.com/articles/article/1/JavaScript%20Browser%20Detection)

Comment: Chrome says "Netscape"

Comment: Firefox 20.0.1 on XP says "Netscape" too.

Comment: Firefox & Chrome say 'Netscape'.  IE 8 says nothing!

Comment: try appcodename http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appcodename.asp

Comment: appCodeName = Mozilla and appName = Netscape in chrome 33

Answer (score 7):

```
//Copy and paste this into your code/text editor, and try it

//Before you use this to fix compatability bugs, it's best to try inform the browser provider that you have found a bug and there latest browser may not be up to date with the current web standards

//Since none of the browsers use the browser identification system properly you need to do something a bit like this

//Write browser identification
document.write(navigator.userAgent + "<br>")

//Detect browser and write the corresponding name
if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0){
    document.write('"MS Internet Explorer ');
    var position = navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") + 5;
    var end = navigator.userAgent.search("; Windows");
    var version = navigator.userAgent.substring(position,end);
    document.write(version + '"');
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0){
document.write('"Google Chrome ');// For some reason in the browser identification Chrome contains the word "Safari" so when detecting for Safari you need to include Not Chrome
    var position = navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") + 7;
    var end = navigator.userAgent.search(" Safari");
    var version = navigator.userAgent.substring(position,end);
    document.write(version + '"');
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0){
    document.write('"Mozilla Firefox ');
    var position = navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") + 8;
    var version = navigator.userAgent.substring(position);
    document.write(version + '"');
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0){//<< Here
    document.write('"Apple Safari ');
    var position = navigator.userAgent.search("Version") + 8;
    var end = navigator.userAgent.search(" Safari");
    var version = navigator.userAgent.substring(position,end);
    document.write(version + '"');
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0){
    document.write('"Opera ');
    var position = navigator.userAgent.search("Version") + 8;
    var version = navigator.userAgent.substring(position);
    document.write(version + '"');
}
else{
    document.write('"Other"');
}

//Use w3schools research the `search()` method as other methods are availible
```

Comment: Please do not recommend w3schools

Comment: And, like a billion other such code snippets, this fails on IE 11 (and presumably later versions).

Comment: "undefined" in Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Since Internet Explorer 11 (IE11+) came out and is not using the tag name of `MSIE` anymore I came up with a variance of an older detection function:

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;

    // if IE11+
    if (new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})").exec(ua) !== null) {
        var M= ["Internet Explorer"];
        if(M && (tem= ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
        M= M? [M[0], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
        return M;
    }

    var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
    if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
    return M;
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, IE11 no longer has `MSIE` in its `navigator.userAgent`:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; BRI/2; BOIE9;ENUS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

As to why you want to know which browser you're using, it's because every browser has its own set of bugs, and you end up implementing browser and version specific workarounds, or tell the user to use a different browser!

Comment: Thats kind of the purpose people would use this for. If they know they will not support IE detect it and let them know.

Answer (score 4):

```
var browser = navigator.appName;
var version = navigator.appVersion;
```

Note, however, that both will not necessarily reflect the truth. Many browsers can be set to mask as other browsers. So, for example, you can't always be sure if a user is actually surfing with IE6 or with Opera that pretends to be IE6.

Comment: +1: contrary to the previous downvote, in theory, this is the right way; in practice, browser vendors fill these values with questionable content; see the docs at MDC ( https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.navigator ) and MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535867%28VS.85%29.aspx ); Google led me also to the follwing page (out of date, no Chrome yet), which shows that it's mainly Safari which reports garbage: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/navigator.shtml

Comment: It is not even the right way in theory - see the HTML5 specification section 6.5.1.1 Client identification, which says of navigator.appName: Must return either the string "Netscape" or the full name of the browser, e.g. "Mellblom Browsernator".  In other words, the HTML5 standard does not even pretend to require that appName have a meaningful value.

Comment: @Spike0xff this answer is from a time where exactly nobody at all was using HTML5, or indeed had so much as heard of it.

Comment: @ЯegDwight (or should I say Elton?): `navigator.appName` has been `"Netscape"` or nothing on pretty much every browser forever, long before the HTML5 spec codified the practice.

Comment: php use optional a browsercap.ini to do that. You may download ?all? possible user agent string from browscap.org . You'll see it's very complex. Additionally all header beginning with HTTP_ may be faked.

Answer (score 3):

This [little library](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) may help you. But be aware that browser detection is not always the solution.

Comment: then, what is the solution ? how can you make style/functionality that depends on the browser or it's version ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I do custom CSS for Internet Explorer:

In my JavaScript file:

```
function isIE () {
      var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(var_isIE){
            if(var_isIE == 10){
                jQuery("html").addClass("ie10");
            }
            if(var_isIE == 8){
                jQuery("html").addClass("ie8");
                // you can also call here some function to disable things that 
                //are not supported in IE, or override browser default styles.
            }
        }
    });
```

And then in my CSS file, y define each different style:

```
.ie10 .some-class span{
    .......
}
.ie8 .some-class span{
    .......
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a function that returns the browser as well as the version, here is an improvement from the original answer:

```
navigator.browserInfo = 
(
    function()
    {
        var browser = '';
        var version = '';
        var idString = '';

        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var tem = [];
        var M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i);

        //IE will be identified as 'Trident' and a different version number. The name must be corrected to 'Internet Explorer' and the correct version identified.
        //ie correction
        if(/trident/i.test(M[1]))
        {
            tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+.?\d*)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            browser = 'Internet Explorer';
            version = tem[1];
        }

        //firefox
        else if(/firefox/i.test(M[1]))
        {
            tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+.?\d*)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            browser = 'Firefox';
            version = tem[1];
        }

        //safari
        else if(/safari/i.test(M[1]))
        {
            tem = ua.match(/\bVersion\/(\d+.?\d*\s*\w+)/);
            browser = 'Safari';
            version = tem[1];
        }

        //If 'Chrome' is found, it may be another browser. 
        else if(M[1] === 'Chrome')
        {
            //opera
            var temOpr = ua.match(/\b(OPR)\/(\d+.?\d*.?\d*.?\d*)/);
            //edge
            var temEdge = ua.match(/\b(Edge)\/(\d+.?\d*)/);
            //chrome
            var temChrome = ua.match(/\b(Chrome)\/(\d+.?\d*.?\d*.?\d*)/);

            //a genuine 'Chrome' reading will result from ONLY temChrome not being null.
            var genuineChrome = temOpr == null && temEdge == null && temChrome != null;

            if(temOpr != null)
            {
                browser = temOpr[1].replace('OPR', 'Opera');
                version = temOpr[2];
            }

            if(temEdge != null)
            {
                browser = temEdge[1];
                version = temEdge[2];
            }

            if(genuineChrome)
            {
                browser = temChrome[1];
                version = temChrome[2];
            }
        }
        //There will be some odd balls, so if you wish to support those browsers, add functionality to display those browsers as well.

        if(browser == '' || version == '')
        {
            idString = 'We couldn\'t find your browser, but you can still use the site';
        }
        else
        {
            idString = browser + ' version ' + version;
        }

        alert('Your browser is ' + idString);

        //store the type of browser locally
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
        {
            //Store
            localStorage.setItem('browser', browser);
            localStorage.setItem('version', version);
        } 
        else
        {
            alert('local storage not available');
        }
    }
)();
```

With this, it also stores the result locally, so this check is not necessary to run every time.

Comment: This is almost an exact copy of the accepted answer. Note that @kennebec's solution returns browser name and version while this version only returns browser name.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hardcoding web browsers, you can scan the user agent to find the browser name:

```
navigator.userAgent.split(')').reverse()[0].match(/(?!Gecko|Version|[A-Za-z]+?Web[Kk]it)[A-Z][a-z]+/g)[0]
```

I've tested this on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. Let me know if you found this doesn't work on a browser.

- Safari: `"Safari"`
- Chrome: `"Chrome"`
- Firefox: `"Firefox"`

You can even modify this to get the browser version if you want. Do note there are better ways to get the browser version

```
navigator.userAgent.split(')').reverse()[0].match(/(?!Gecko|Version|[A-Za-z]+?Web[Kk]it)[A-Z][a-z]+\/[\d.]+/g)[0].split('/')
```

Sample output:

```
Firefox/39.0
```

Comment: Does not work well with some different browsers - It points UCBrowser as Chrome, even when in IE Compatibility mode, lol

Comment: It says Edge is Chrome...

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm using:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var info = {
        browser: /Edge\/\d+/.test(ua) ? 'ed' : /MSIE 9/.test(ua) ? 'ie9' : /MSIE 10/.test(ua) ? 'ie10' : /MSIE 11/.test(ua) ? 'ie11' : /MSIE\s\d/.test(ua) ? 'ie?' : /rv\:11/.test(ua) ? 'ie11' : /Firefox\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'ff' : /Chrom(e|ium)\W\d|CriOS\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'gc' : /\bSafari\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'sa' : /\bOpera\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'op' : /\bOPR\W\d/i.test(ua) ? 'op' : typeof MSPointerEvent !== 'undefined' ? 'ie?' : '',
        os: /Windows NT 10/.test(ua) ? "win10" : /Windows NT 6\.0/.test(ua) ? "winvista" : /Windows NT 6\.1/.test(ua) ? "win7" : /Windows NT 6\.\d/.test(ua) ? "win8" : /Windows NT 5\.1/.test(ua) ? "winxp" : /Windows NT [1-5]\./.test(ua) ? "winnt" : /Mac/.test(ua) ? "mac" : /Linux/.test(ua) ? "linux" : /X11/.test(ua) ? "nix" : "",
        touch: 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement,
        mobile: /IEMobile|Windows Phone|Lumia/i.test(ua) ? 'w' : /iPhone|iP[oa]d/.test(ua) ? 'i' : /Android/.test(ua) ? 'a' : /BlackBerry|PlayBook|BB10/.test(ua) ? 'b' : /Mobile Safari/.test(ua) ? 's' : /webOS|Mobile|Tablet|Opera Mini|\bCrMo\/|Opera Mobi/i.test(ua) ? 1 : 0,
        tablet: /Tablet|iPad/i.test(ua),
};
```

`info` properties:

- `browser`: `gc` for Google Chrome; `ie9`-`ie11` for IE; `ie?` for old or unknown IE; `ed` for Edge; `ff` for Firefox; `sa` for Safari; `op` for Opera.
- `os`: `mac` `win7` `win8` `win10` `winnt` `winxp` `winvista` `linux` `nix`
- `mobile`: `a` for Android; `i` for iOS (iPhone iPad); `w` for Windows Phone; `b` for Blackberry; `s` for undetected mobile running Safari; `1` for other undetected mobile; `0` for non-mobile
- `touch`: `true` for touch enabled devices, including touch laptops/notebooks that has both mouse and touch together; `false` for no touch support
- `tablet`: `true` or `false`

https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/ncb4n882/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery library to detect the browser version.

**Example:**

jQuery.browser.version

However, this only makes sense if you are also using other functions of jQuery. Adding an entire library just to detect the browser seems like overkill to me.

**More information:**
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

(you have to scroll down a bit)

Comment: I've just tried on win 8 chrome 25 and ie 10. Well, it fails completely. After 3 years any current support would be nice.

Comment: This feature was deprecated at jQuery 1.3, and finally removed at jQuery 1.9. So, it's best to not rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') >= 0;
        // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
        var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
        var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
        // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
        var isChrome = !!window.chrome;                          // Chrome 1+
        var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
```

you can more read
[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm WAY late to this question, but figured I'd throw my snippets up here. A lot of the answers here are OK, and, as one points out, it's generally best to use `feature detection` rather than rely on the `userAgent` string. However, if you are going to go that route, I've written a complete snippet, as well as an alternate jQuery implementation to replace the depricated `$.browser`.

---

### Vanilla JS

My first snippet simply adds four properties to the `navigator` object: `browser`, `version`, `mobile`, & `webkit`.

### jsFiddle

- [GitHub](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/navigator-extensions)
- [min](https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/navigator-extensions/master/navigator.ext.min.js)

---

```
/** navigator [extended]
 *  Simply extends Browsers navigator Object to include browser name, version number, and mobile type (if available).
 *
 *  @property {String} browser The name of the browser.
 *  @property {Double} version The current Browser version number.
 *  @property {String|Boolean} mobile Will be `false` if is not found to be mobile device. Else, will be best guess Name of Mobile Device (not to be confused with browser name)
 *  @property {Boolean} webkit If is webkit or not.
 */
;(function(){function c(){try{switch(!0){case /MSIE|Trident/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"MSIE";case /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Chrome";case /Opera/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Opera";case /Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return/Silk/i.test(navigator.userAgent)?"Silk":"Kindle";case /BlackBerry/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"BlackBerry";case /PlayBook/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"PlayBook";case /BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Blackberry";
case /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Android";case /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Safari";case /Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Mozilla";case /Nokia/.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Nokia"}}catch(a){console.debug("ERROR:setBrowser\t",a)}}function d(){try{switch(!0){case /Sony[^ ]*/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Sony";case /RIM Tablet/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"RIM Tablet";case /BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"BlackBerry";case /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"iPhone";
case /iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"iPad";case /iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"iPod";case /Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Opera Mini";case /IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"IEMobile";case /BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"BlackBerry";case /Nokia/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Nokia";case /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return"Android"}}catch(a){console.debug("ERROR:setMobile\t",a)}return!1}function e(){try{switch(!0){case /MSIE|Trident/i.test(navigator.userAgent):return/Trident/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&
/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(navigator.userAgent)?parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))?parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):"Edge";case /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent):return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""));case /Opera/.test(navigator.userAgent):return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("Version/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,
""));case /Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(navigator.userAgent):if(/Silk/i.test(navigator.userAgent))return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""));if(/Kindle/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&/Version/i.test(navigator.userAgent))return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""));case /BlackBerry/.test(navigator.userAgent):return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,
""));case /PlayBook/.test(navigator.userAgent):case /BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(navigator.userAgent):case /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent):return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""));case /Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent):return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split(/Firefox\//i)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""));case /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent):return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,
""));case /Nokia/.test(navigator.userAgent):return parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.split("Browser")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))}}catch(a){console.debug("ERROR:setVersion\t",a)}}a:{try{if(navigator&&navigator.userAgent){navigator.browser=c();navigator.mobile=d();navigator.version=e();var b;b:{try{b=/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent);break b}catch(a){console.debug("ERROR:setWebkit\t",a)}b=void 0}navigator.webkit=b;break a}}catch(a){}throw Error("Browser does not support `navigator` Object |OR| has undefined `userAgent` property.");
}})();
/*  simple c & p of above   */
```

---

Comment: I tried you code(Vanilla JS) .. when I tried with Firefox and opera from mobile browser it did not give the right output

Comment: @RajaDhasan Vanilla version updated. Try it now.

Comment: It works perfectly from web browser .. but  when I tried from android mobile for chrome browser it prints Android and for opera it prints chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
// Chrome 1+
var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping:<hr>';
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>';
output += 'isSafari: ' + isSafari + '<br>';
output += 'isOpera: ' + isOpera + '<br>';
output += 'isIE: ' + isIE + '<br>';
output += 'isIE Edge: ' + isEdge + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but close to it:

```
var jscriptVersion = /*@cc_on @if(@_jscript) @_jscript_version @else @*/ false /*@end @*/;
var geckoVersion = navigator.product === 'Gecko' && navigator.productSub;
var operaVersion = 'opera' in window && 'version' in opera && opera.version();
```

The variables will contain the appropriate version or `false` if it is not available.

I'd appreciate it if someone using Chrome could find out if you can use `window.chrome` in a similar way to `window.opera`.

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting and quicker way.
IE supports `navigator.systemLanguage` which returns "en-US" where other browsers return `undefined`.

```
<script>
    var lang = navigator.systemLanguage;
    if (lang!='en-US'){document.write("Well, this is not internet explorer");}
    else{document.write("This is internet explorer");}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times we need simple method to check if the browser is IE or not. This is how it could be:

```
 var isMSIE = (/trident/i).test(navigator.userAgent);

 if(isMSIE)
 {
  /* do something for ie */
 }
 else
 {
  /* do something else */
 }
```

or simplified siva's method:

```
 if(!!navigator.systemLanguage)
 {
  /* do something for ie */
 }
 else
 {
  /* do something else */
 }
```

MSIE v.11 check:

```
if( (/trident/i).test(navigator.userAgent) && (/rv:/i).test(navigator.userAgent) )
{
  /* do something for ie 11 */
}
```

other IE browsers contain MSIE string in their userAgent property and could be catched by it.

Comment: As per many other answers to this question, it is much better to do feature detection than browser detection.

Comment: Other ways to detect IE browsers including both feature and ie string detection in user agent. `if( (/MSIE/i).test(navigator.userAgent) && !!window.MSInputMethodContext ) { /* ie check */ }` or `if( !!window.MSInputMethodContext ) { /* ie 11 check */ }`

Answer (score 0):

I make this small function, hope it helps. Here you can find the latest version 
[browserDetection](https://gist.github.com/alejandrorangel/e6c31177047dbcc16ae512f02064edd7)

```
function detectBrowser(userAgent){
  var chrome  = /.*(Chrome\/).*(Safari\/).*/g;
  var firefox = /.*(Firefox\/).*/g;
  var safari  = /.*(Version\/).*(Safari\/).*/g;
  var opera   = /.*(Chrome\/).*(Safari\/).*(OPR\/).*/g

  if(opera.exec(userAgent))
    return "Opera"
  if(chrome.exec(userAgent))
    return "Chrome"
  if(safari.exec(userAgent))
    return "Safari"
  if(firefox.exec(userAgent))
    return "Firefox"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code snippet will show how how you can show UI elemnts depends on IE version and browser

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var msiVersion = GetMSIieversion();
if ((msiVersion <= 8) && (msiVersion != false)) {

    //Show UI elements specific to IE version 8 or low

    } else {
    //Show UI elements specific to IE version greater than 8 and for other browser other than IE,,ie..Chrome,Mozila..etc
    }
}
);
```

Below code will give how we can get IE version

```
function GetMSIieversion() {

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
if (msie > 0) {
    // IE 10 or older => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
}

var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
if (trident > 0) {
    // IE 11 => return version number
    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
    return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
}

var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
if (edge > 0) {
    // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
}

// other browser like Chrome,Mozila..etc
return false;

}
```