# How to detect my browser version and operating system using Html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

the code should be appear in browser OUTPUT like

Browser Name: Netscape

Browser Version: 5.0 
Platform / operating system: Win32/linux/mac

Comment: It is rare that you actually need this information -- what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant get in CSS but can get in JavaScript

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp

```
<script>

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent language: " + navigator.systemLanguage + "</p>";

console.log(txt);

</script>
```

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript