# CSS affect MAC chrome browser only?

Tags: html, css

Am looking for styles which affects only to the MAC chrome browser? (MAC chrome and safari will be also fine) Could you any body help me on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript .. see this and add css accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ya, this what am looking for,...

Answer (score 0):

window.navigator is the simplest way to get information about the user's browser and OS. Basic string search from there to look for OS X. So, using a little Javascript:

```
var useros = window.navigator.appVersion;
var element = window.getElementById("elementyouwanttostyle");

if (useros.indexOf('OS X') > -1) {
    element.style.color = red;
}
```

Sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator