# How to detect os version using javascript

Tags: javascript, operating-system

how to detect the OS version like windows NT 6.1 will give 6.1, windows NT 5.1 will give 5.1 using javascript

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Comment: that is using index of with NT 6.1, but is it possible to get 6.1 without adding it to index of like get version?

Answer (score 1):

navigator.appVersion will give you Os information.And you can use it as:

document.write(navigator.appVersion);

Answer (score -2):

To detect the operating system on the client machine, your script can analyze the value of navigator.appVersion or navigator.userAgent. Below is a simple example of a script that sets the variable OSName to reflect the actual client OS.
for example,

```
 var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
```

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);

Comment: The question is specifically asking for the *version* not the platform.