# browser/OS detection for Android/iOS/Windows/OSX - IE 9+, firefox Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

**Not A Duplicate Of**
[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)
The other questions does not address OS detection.  And it is from 2012.

I have an app that supports iOS/Android/IE9+/Firefox/Safari/Chrome, but user needs to download different binaries depends on the browser/OS type.

So on the "download" page, I need to guide user to different download URLs depend on:

- Android(4.2+) any browser - download app from [google play store URL]
- iOS(7+) any browser - download app from [apple app store URL]
- IE9+/Firefox on Windows - download "plugin.exe"
- Safari on OSX - download "plugin.pkg"
- Chrome on Win/OSX - no need plugin download

All other browser/OS are not supported; need to notify user to either install Chrome(on Win/OSX) or use mobile app.

**Question: How can I detect all these things in one web page?**

Libraries I have found on Google, but not quite confident that they are the **prefered** way to do it.
https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js
https://github.com/WhichBrowser/WhichBrowser

Please **don't** ask me to do **feature detection**, it is not about using an HTML5 feature.

Comment: You link to [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser), but you do not specify how your question differs from it except for the specific version numbers and places you wish to link to.

Comment: @David Mulder I appreciate your help but you didn't read my question content.  I need to differentiate browsers on Android/iOS/OSX/WIN.

Comment: Yeah, which is described in various of those answers (which are from 2014 for the record). Either way, if your problem is differentiating between operating systems it's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Comment: @David Mulder the other QA is from 2012 as well.  Three years in browser & OS is like three generations old.  I can hack with user-agent string easily, but not sure about what is the latest best practice.