# Change site depending on user agent

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I would like to change things on my site depending on the user agent. Specifically I want to change the text and url of a download button so that when a user is on Ubuntu/Linux, Arch/Linux, Debian-based/linux, Mac OS X, or Windows they are are presented with info and a download button that will be reverent to them.  Kinda like [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/) does.

I would like to do this in JavaScript and not on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript).

Comment: Bad idea. Are you going to support these operating systems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_operating_systems ? What if the users main operating system is different to that of the VM OS?

Comment: Jeff we are going to add a link to switch OS like LibreOffice does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional on [these variables](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) to apply to appropriate changes to the site's styles or DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the `navigator.appVersion` property:

```
function isOS(str){
    str = str.toLowerCase()
    var os_ver = navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase().substring(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("(")+1, navigator.appVersion.indexOf(")"))
    return ~os_ver.indexOf(str)
}
```

This should work. I know it works for windows.