# How to prompt user to download app when visiting product page?

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, plugins, user-experience

Recently I was browsing a website from my iPhone and it prompted me to download their app at the top of the browser.
We are also having same kind of app in iTunes and wants our users to see the notification same as theirs. Attaching a screen-shot.
Anybody suggest how is this achieved?Through some script or plugins.
Help us to integrate this.

[image]

Comment: you want to get it done by someone?

Comment: No, I want to know how this is achieved. Is it using some kinda plugins or scripting?

Comment: detect operating system using php webpage http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-detect-operating-system-using-php-in-webpage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user visits your webpage, you can check the browser & OS of device requesting the webpage. Depending upon this information, you can write the script to navigate user to your app download link. Check [How to detect my browser version and operating system using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript) for reference.

Comment: That was a brilliant approach. I didn't even thought about that aspect. Thank you dude!

Comment: Checkout this apple built in way: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: So, what OP is showing in that screenshot is not some built in prompt trigger via something like a meta tag?

Comment: meta tags are supported only on iOS platform. see https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-an-ios-and-android-smart-app-banner-with-deep-linking-and-download-tracking/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is using [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners), Safari builds the banner
in it's UI, is not part of the web page.

> Just as [Michael Tarimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792092/michael-tarimo) says in the comments of the accepted answer.