# Is there a method to output the version of chrome in the console?

Tags: browser

I want to check out the version of chrome in such an easy way with the browser's debugger tool.

Comment: this questions was already asked please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Comment: Have look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) also. Similar kind of question is asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`navigator.userAgent` gives you that data (among other things in the user agent string).

To get just the Chrome version, try this:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome\/(\S*)/)[1]
```